# Attribute_error in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Создал класс "аккаунта в банке", аттрибуты и методы для него. При вызове функции отображается и спрашивается выбор действия, после чего вылазит ошибка, например:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'acc_c'

Сам код:

```
class BankAccount:
    def  __init__(self,name,acc_n,acc_c):
        """name-имя,acc_n-номер счёта,acc_c-состояние счёта"""
        self.name=name="Den"
        self.acc_n=acc_n= 2628351
        self.acc_c=acc_c=25.50
    def operation(self,ca,am,wm):
        """ca-вывод счёта на экран,am-добавление денег,wm-вывод денег"""
        deistvie=input("Какую операцию хотите сделать со счётом?(ca,am,wm)")
        if deistvie=='ca':
            ca=("Денег на счёте: "+self.acc_c)
            print(ca)
        elif deistvie=='am':
            am=int(input("Какую сумму хотите положить на счёт? "))
            am_2=self.acc_c+am
            print(am_2)
        elif deistvie=='wm':
            wm=int(input("Какую сумму хотите снять со счёта? "))
        wm_2=self.acc_c-wm
        print(wm_2)
    operation(" "," "," "," " )#вызов функции operation
```

Answer (score 1):

**Изучайте синтаксис Python 3 и ОПП**

```
class BankAccount:
        def  __init__(self, name=None, account_number=0, state_of_account=0):
            self.name = name
            self.account_number = account_number
            self.state_of_account = state_of_account
            self.run()

        def run(self):
            print("Для выхода нажмите q")
            while True:
                operation = input("Какую операцию хотите сделать со счётом? (check, +, -, q)")
                if operation == "check":
                    print("Денег на счёте: " + str(self.state_of_account))
                elif operation == "+":
                    add = int(input("Какую сумму хотите положить на счёт?"))
                    self.state_of_account += add
                elif operation == "-":
                    verb = int(input("Какую сумму хотите снять со счёта? "))
                    self.state_of_account -= verb
                elif operation == "q":
                    break

BankAccount("Bob", 123543, 20000)
```